# Swift how to safe user login session with checkbox "Remember Me"

Tags: swift, authentication, checkbox, textfield, usersession

i have a question about my app that i develop, in my login screen i have this checkbox when the user check that box, his username(or in my case his phone number to login) will automatically safe in the textfield where if the user logout, his phone number will automatically fill in the textfield.

Where if the user not check that box, his phone number will not gonna safe in the user session so when the user logout, his phone number will not fill the login textfield.

that checkBox is for "remember me", when user check that box it will remember the user phone number and if not check the box it will not remember the user phone for the next time the user login.

any idea how guys?

[image]

heres my code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    rememberMeFlag = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "REMEMBER_USER")
    checkBoxBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleCheckBox(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    checkBoxBtn.isSelected = rememberMeFlag

    if rememberMeFlag {
        let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USER_TELEPHONE")
        textPhoneNumber.text = save_session!.substring(from: 1)
    }

    textPhoneNumber.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

}

@IBAction func toggleCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if sender.isSelected == true {
        checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked-1"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = false
    }else{
        checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unCheck"), for: .normal)
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
    
}


//this code is for user session
if FIRST_BOOT {
        print("first boot")
        if let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USER_FULLNAME") {
            USER_FULLNAME = save_session
        }
        if let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "SESSION_TOKEN") {
            SESSION_TOKEN = save_session
        }
        if let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USER_PIN") {
            USER_PIN = save_session
        }
        if let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USER_TELEPHONE") {
            USER_TELEPHONE = save_session
        }
       
        if let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "IDENTITY_NUMBER") {
            IDENTITY_NUMBER = save_session
        }
        
        if let _ = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "WIZARD") {
            // Wizard has opened
        } else {
            //performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToWizard", sender: nil)
            
            //return
        }



  //i use that code to put the user phone num into the textfield
if let save_session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USER_TELEPHONE_CACHED") {
        textPhoneNumber.text = save_session.substring(from: 1)
    }
```

can anyone tell me how to do the thing that i want? i want just to put that user session inside the checkbox func but i just see alot of bugs after that, im asking about the steps on how to do it, cause im kinda confused how even though its seems not so difficult.... thanks guys.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? Do you get the values back from the UserDefaults? Where do you save them? Also remember to store the "remember me" state in the User Defaults, and to delete the values if the user un-selects "remember me".

Comment: yeah so basically im puting this new feature that when user check remember me box, my app will save his phone number the next time he logout and login again, and the way i want it is to put user phone number automatically into textfield. so user just have to insert pin next time the user login. but if the user dont check that box user have to fill both phone number and pin

Comment: So you don't have a detailled technical question, but rather want to know what checks and steps to perform in which order?

Comment: emmm yeahh basicly sir, can you show me how or maybe tell me if theres any similar guide that i can follow up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

- when the user checks or unchecks "remember me", update an instance variable `rememberMeFlag` and store this information in the user defaults
- when the user edits the telephone text field and `rememberMeFlag` is `true`, save the contents to the user defaults
- when the view loads, read the values from the user defaults and update `rememberMeFlag`, the checkbox and the text field

So the code might look like this:

```
class X: UIViewController {
    
    private var rememberMeFlag = false
    @IBOutlet weak var rememberMeSwitch:UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var telephoneTextField:UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        rememberMeFlag = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "REMEMBER_USER")
        rememberMeSwitch.isOn = rememberMeFlag
        
        if rememberMeFlag {
            let tel = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "USER_TELEPHONE")
            telephoneTextField.text = tel
        }
        
        // connect actions; do this in code like here
        // or use outlet connections from the storyboard
        telephoneTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        rememberMeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    @IBAction func toggleCheckBox(_ sender: UIButton) {
        rememberMeFlag = !rememberMeFlag
        UserDefaults.standard.set(rememberMeFlag, forKey: "REMEMBER_USER")

        if rememberMeFlag == true {
            checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Checked-1"), for: .normal)
            let text = telephoneTextField.text
            UserDefaults.standard.set(text, forKey:"USER_TELEPHONE")
        } else {
            checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unCheck"), for: .normal)
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "USER_TELEPHONE")
        }   
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ sender: UITextField){
        guard rememberMeFlag else { return }
        let text = telephoneTextField.text
        UserDefaults.standard.set(text, forKey:"USER_TELEPHONE")
    }
}
```

Comment: ahhh thank you sir for your answer, im going to try your answer and your method

Comment: sir i have this problem, you using uiSwitch, and im using this checkbox button, i cant seem to pass if the button is checked or not in viewdidload, i try to using btn.isSelected, but it seems does not work

Comment: What exactly is your Checkbox Button? Seems to be some third-party component. Can you post a link to the docs of the checkbox?

Comment: my Checkbox button is actually just an button with image which i as i describe the method above on my code, im not using any third party im just using button and image sir

Comment: sir, im sorry if i ask to much, but i still dont get what should i put in the viewDidLoad, cause in viewDidLoad you put in the uiSwitch, i try to implement by using the checkbox button but it still not work, i update the code on my question. thank you sir

Comment: thanks you sir i finally figure it out, thanks for your help sir